# Книги для программистов

Tags: книги

Есть какие-нибудь книги которые должен прочитать каждый хороший программист?

Comment: А что в Вашем понимании хороший программист?
А хороших книг по программированию много, но все они касаются какого то языка и какой то операционной системы.
Универсальной книги наверное нет.
разве что какая не будь книга по системам исчислениям и алгоритморике, это в принципе общее у всех языков и осей.

Comment: Школьный учебник по русскому языку

Comment: Алгоритмы надо знать всем, вне зависимости от языка и ОСи.

Comment: Причём все алгоритмы. Если пропущен хоть один -- вся работа насмарку.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Любые книги, где описывается следующие:

---

1. **Структуры данных:**

   - Массивы и строки
   - Связанные списки
   - Стек и очередь
   - Деревья и графы
2. **Алгоритмы и «концепции»:**

   - Сортировка и поиск
   - Рекурсия
   - Манипуляция битами
   - Объектно-ориентированное проектирование
3. **Язык программирования**
4. **Операционные системы**
5. Дизайн и юзабилити(опционально)

Comment: Существуют совершенно отвратительные книги по указанным темам. И они подпадают под категорию "любые". И их не должен читать каждый хороший программист. Ваш ответ неверен.

Comment: по вашему списку надо не книги читать а статейки в гугле...

Comment: думаю, при поиске книг по описаным мной темам пользователь сам оценит отзывы и оценки к ним и решит стоит их читать или нет, я просто указал направление, в котором стоит искать, т.к. однозначно "лучшей" книги по той или иной теме объективно не существует

Answer (score 6):

Книги, которые мне кажется, обязательно должен прочитать каждый:
 1. [Макконнелл С. Совершенный код](http://www.piter.com/book.phtml?978546900822)
 2. [Мартин Фаулер. Рефакторинг. Улучшение существующего кода](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1308678/)
 3. Если с паттернами никогда не встречались, то [Фримен Э. Паттерны проектирования](http://www.piter.com/book.phtml?978545900435) и затем уже знаменитую книгу [Приемы объектно-ориентированного проектирования. Паттерны проектирования](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2457392/).

Конечно это не полный список, но для начала хватит.

Comment: абсолютно поддерживаю.

Comment: @sharok, первая ссылка уже не действительна.

Comment: @Ilja, обратите внимание на дату ответа. Естественно, за это время ссылки могут стать недействительными.

С другой стороны, не думаю, что у кого-то могут возникнуть затруднения при поиске данных книг в поисковике по названию и автору.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, будет интересно и полезно познакомится с ассемблером. Сейчас это может показаться лишним (не нужным и не современным), но посмотреть, так сказать, на "внутренности" всех действий поможет еще в большей степени понять программисту, что именно происходит с машиной.

Comment: Ну без знаний систем исчеслений ассемблер ему будет по барабану.
Я считаю что Асм учить нужно когда имеешь представление мало-мальски о программировании.
Тем более на начальном этапе , ему глубоко фиолетово в каком регистре что, и что в стеке.

Comment: он не спрашивает, с чего начать изучение программирования, а что должен знать программист в конечном итоге.

Comment: В конечном итоге программист должен знать то, за что ему платят, и то, как сэкономить свое время на разработке чего-либо за счет новых технологий. Учиться придется каждый день всю жизнь. Так что что будет знать программист в итоге - никто сказать не может. А азы - увы, но это не си, не ассемблер, а высшая математика.

Comment: одно другому не мешает.

Comment: Азы это высшая математика? О_о<br>
Я даже алгебру нормально не помню, а вы тут о высшей математике...<br>
Быть может я конечно не программист и не заслужено ем свой хлеб, но это врятли и ИМХО математика мягко говоря не является решающим фактором... Тем более у тру программиста все вообще очень просто,1 и 0 :D<br>
Естественно если речь не идет о программировании на ассамблере ^^

Comment: Дискретка нужна: сложения, пересечения множеств, логика. Понимание функций, умение сокращать aka оптимизировать выражение. Больше от матана ничего не нужно - во всяком случае, 5 лет учиться, чтобы за 5 лет работы *не* потратить час на википедию, по-моему, неразумно.

Comment: Вот и я об этом, я не говорю о том что в программировании не надо обладать математическим складом ума... Естественно надо, но надо ли так углубляться в вышку? Очень большой вопрос...

Answer (score 2):

Трехтомник Кнута?

Comment: После 5 лет опыта программирования, не раньше

Comment: Да, и после мехматовского курса математики

Comment: +1. Кнут для начинающих будет неподъемен. Нужно что-то более простое и наглядное.

Comment: Кнута нужно уметь читать. Кнут - это не художественная литература, а энциклопедия. Кто же читает энциклопедии от корочки до корочки? ну пару безумцев.
Кнута нужно читать так. Прочитать пару первых глав, потом внимательно пройтись по всему содержанию. Найти темы, которые раньше встречались в жизни  (к примеру, сортировка, случайные числа), почитать хотя бы по диагонали эти главы.
Потом, в будущем, когда возникнет задача, через несколько минут возникнет желание подглянуть в Кнута, подумать и написать красивое решение.

Comment: > Опасайтесь багов в приведенном выше коде; я только доказал корректность, но не запускал его.

Donald E. Knuth.

Comment: Немножко нестандартная, но просто обычная EULA. А то кто то самолеты будет запускать, а те - упадут. И кто виноват? А так он просто перестраховывается.

Comment: ну, вообще-то книга эта писалась именно как учебник для последовательного изучения, с упражнениями и контрольными вопросами.

Comment: ну так для кого Кнут написал - "остерегайтесь багов в приведенном тексте"(код это ведь текст и наоборот. А учитывая, что он это в TeX делает:))) )
Поэтому, для некоторых это баг в книге, что ее нужно читать полностью:)

Answer (score 1):

Немного конкретики: мне многие советовали "Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ" Кормена, Лейзерсона, Ривеста и Штайна. Сам пока прочитал несколько глав, написано вполне толково. Требования к текущим знаниям три: знание хоть какого-нибудь языка (но не Php или т.п., конечно), знания в математике (на первые главы хватит понятия о функциях) и голова на плечах.

Comment: на мой взгляд, слишком заумно всё у них.

Comment: Тут народ Кнута предлагает, по сравнению с ним - детский лепет)